# Удаление пустых папок

Tags: python

Задача - удалить пустые папки. Код внизу удаляет только последнюю папку и отключается. Но, после удаления последней папки, папка, в которой она находилась тоже становится пустой. Как заставить скрипт после удаления последней папки проверять ту папку, из которой он удалил последнюю и удалял ее?

```
def del_empty_dirs(path):
    for d in os.listdir(path):
        a = os.path.join(path, d)
        if os.path.isdir(a):
            if not os.listdir(a):
                os.rmdir(a)
                print(a, 'удалена')
            else:
                del_empty_dirs(a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам нужен поиск в глубину..
Сначала углубляемся в рекурсию, только потом что-то проверяем/удаляем:

```
def del_empty_dirs(path):
    for d in os.listdir(path):
        a = os.path.join(path, d)
        if os.path.isdir(a):
            del_empty_dirs(a)
            if not os.listdir(a):
                os.rmdir(a)
                print(a, 'удалена')
```

Таким образом, мы гарантируем, что по выходу из рекурсивного вызова - все дочерние папки уже обработаны.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!